# Why is i in my code not considered an integer?

Tags: python

Im new to Python and am trying to write a function that returns the amount of 1s in a binary number (i.e if the input is 12, then it should return 2, since 12 is 1100 in binary. However I keep getting the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" and I don't know whats wrong, I have googled the problem but havent understood what the answers meant.

Heres the code (I know it could be shorter I'm just asking the question because I get this error often and don't know why it comes):

```
def count_ones(num):
x=0
for i in bin(num):
    if list(bin(num))[i] ==1:
        x += 1
return x
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the the number of zeros and ones of a binary number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517570/get-the-the-number-of-zeros-and-ones-of-a-binary-number-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Simply, `bin(x)` returns a string representing the binary number, as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) point out.

So `for i in bin(num):` iterates over the characters in that string.

You can achieve what you want by checking if `i == '1'` instead, so your code would be

```
def count_ones(num):
    x=0
    for i in bin(num):
        if i == '1':
            x += 1
    return x
```

Consider simplifying your function, however, by using the `count` method to count the occurrences of `'1'` in the binary representation, as follows:

```
def count_ones(num):
    return bin(num).count('1')
```

Comment: but shouldn't   list(bin(num))[i] ==1: make the string a list?

Comment: the string can already, for your purposes, be treated as a list of characters

Answer (score 1):

`bin` returns a string, where you are iterating over each bit as a string. You should use `int(i)`. You should probably use `format` or `str.format` to remove the `0b` prefix as b is not an integer.

```py
for i in format(num, 'b'):
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a generator expression for this.

```
def count_ones(num):
    return sum(1 for digit in bin(num) if digit == '1')
```

Example

```
>>> count_ones(50)
3
>>> bin(50)
'0b110010'
```

For what it's worth, the reason your code is not working is that `bin` returns a string, so each element you loop over will by of type `str` not `int`.